# control re-sizing and repeating of a background image in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that shows a fragment of a city skyline. It has to be placed like a decorative ribbon across the background. Most unfortunately, the picture itself is not mine, I access something available on the web, and it is protected by copyright, so i can't download/save it and amend it in any way or manner.

I need to resolve two issues:

- The picture is is too large (height), I have to scale it down;
- I only need to repeat 'horizontally', in one row, 
  without covering the entire background in "tiles"

Comment: I guess i got the answer already, using repeat-x solves one problem. With scaling, I basically need something that will do "background-image scale 70%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize the picture with css using `background-size`.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Use `background-repeat: repeat-x;` to repeat it horizontally.

Comment: The concern I have though is that you state "the picture itself is not mine...protected by copyright."  I'm sure you wouldn't want that happening to you.  You can easily purchase a stock photo from any number of sites online, or do a google image search with the parameter of "labeled for reuse".

Comment: Thanks, it helps. I'm working on the demo, that shows how to share web content among multiple web portals. My client have one website already designed and running, with content and styles etc and they want to make sure that when they build the new one (using my product) , they don't have to redevelop everything from scratch, but rather can leverage whatever they already have and achieve similar look and feel.